# Connect to MQTT using IIS rewrite URL

Tags: docker, iis, url-rewriting, mqtt

I have a windows vm (with a DNS name:https://subdomain.domain.com) that access software on this server.
Next to that in the same vnet I have a linux (ubuntu) vm with docker core running and a Mosquitto mqtt container.

This is my mqtt config file (for tests it's not secure yet, have to add users later):

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
listener 9001

## Authentication ##
allow_anonymous true
```

In my docker compose this is configured as followed:

```
 mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    hostname: mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto:/mosquitto
      - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - ./mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/etc/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
```

I know want to connect to **https://subdomain.domain.com/mqtt** and be able to connect to my mqtt docker container. For this I use a IIS URL rewrite as followed:
[image]

If I then test my link (https://subdomain.domain.com/mqtt) I get a 502 response.
However if I connect directly to the server on mqtt://[ip of server]:9001 it is working.

Anybody any idea what is wrong, or should be configured differently?

Already tried following things:

- connection on port 1883 and 9001
- changed connection link to mqtt://xxx
- looked around for fixes in mqtt config or docker compose

Comment: First have you missed out a `protocol websockets` from your mosquitto.conf? And you should not be using `mqtt://` for websocket connections, you should be using `ws://` (and websockets is the ONLY protocol you will get to work with ISS proxying, not native MQTT)

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 502 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I got it working using ws:// using the direct ip of the server and on port 9001. However the connection drops from time to time. Is this because of how web sockets work? In comparison with mqtt:// who is continuously up? However it's not working with the url rewrite